# Update search results from api when value changes

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a search bar that will perform a search function based off user input. When the user searches a list is populated (ie. this is a meal app, so if they search for "eggs" a list will be populated showing results of search)

My issue is when the user completes there first search and wants to type again to find a new value (food), the list does not populate again. The API still makes the call, but I'm having trouble updating the list. I tried adding `removeAll()` to the array `onSubmit` but it didn't work as expected.

```
struct FoodSearchResultsView: View {
    //calls API
    @EnvironmentObject private var foodApi: FoodApiSearch
    //textfield input
    @State private var searchResultsItem = ""
    //if toggled, will display, binded to search bar
    @Binding var userSearch: Bool
    //var holds if textfield typing is complete by user
    @Binding var textComplete: Bool
    //triggers select breakfast, lunch, dinner optins
    
    //when false, api results will not display
    @State private var isViewSearching = false
    
    var body: some View {
        if userSearch{
            VStack{
                Text(isViewSearching ? "Results" : "Searching..")
                Spacer()
                
              //  delays showing api call
                    .onAppear {
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.7) {
                                   self.isViewSearching = true
                               }
                           }
                //if user has completed searching for a food
                if isViewSearching{
                    List(foodApi.userSearchResults){meal in
                        VStack{
                            HStack{
                                VStack(alignment: .leading){
                                    Text(meal.mealName)
                                    HStack{
                                        Text(meal.calories + " cals, ")
                                            .font(.caption)
                                            .offset(y:8)
                                        Text(meal.brand)
                                            .font(.caption)
                                            .offset(y:8)
                                    }
                                    
                                    }
                                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                                
                                Spacer()
                                Image(systemName: "plus.app")
                                    .font(.title2)
                                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                    .offset(x: 30)
                            }
                        
                        .frame(width:200, height:40) //width of background
                        .padding([.leading, .trailing], 60)
                        .padding([.top, .bottom], 10)
                        .background(RoundedRectangle(
                            cornerRadius:20).fill(Color("LightWhite")))
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                         Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(height:800)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**SearchBar**

```
struct MealSearchBar: View {
    //TEXTFIELD
    @State var userFoodInput = ""
    @State private var didtextComplete = false
    //if user seached for a meal
    @State private var didUserSearch = false
    //calls search API
    @StateObject private var foodApi = FoodApiSearch()
    
    var body: some View {
       
        VStack{
            ZStack{
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(Color("LightWhite"))
                HStack{
                    Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                    
                    TextField("Enter Food", text: $userFoodInput)
                        .onSubmit {
                            foodApi.searchFood(userItem: userFoodInput)
                            didUserSearch = true
                            userFoodInput = ""
                        }
                       
                    
                    //Text(foodApi.foodDescription)
                }
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .padding(.leading, 13)
                
               
            }
            
            .frame(height:40)
            .cornerRadius(15)
            .padding(12)
        }
        
        FoodSearchResultsView(userSearch: $didUserSearch, textComplete: $didtextComplete)
            .environmentObject(foodApi)
    }
    
}
```

I only attached my results view and searchbar that calls the view. I believe the issue is happening onSubmit of the textfield, if you need the api call as well, will be happy to supply it, but to confirm again for clarity, despite the list not refreshing, the API is still updating, despite the list not updating.

Update: Added API Call

```
class FoodApiSearch: ObservableObject{
    var userSearchResults: [Meal] = Array()
    @Published var foodUnit = ""
    @Published var calories = ""
    @Published var brand = ""
    
    //will search for user Input
    func searchFood(userItem: String){
       ///IMPROVE API FUNCTION LATER ON DURING LAUNCH
        ///
        let urlEncoded = userItem.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .alphanumerics)
           guard
                let url = URL(string: "https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/foods/search?&api_key=****GWtDvDZVOy8cqG&query=\(urlEncoded!)") else {return}
                URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _,_) in
                    let searchResults = try! JSONDecoder().decode(APISearchResults.self, from: data!)   
                    DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
                        var counter = 0
                            for item in searchResults.foods ?? []{
                                if (counter < 5){
                                    self.userSearchResults.append(Meal(
                                        id: UUID(),
                                        brand: item.brandOwner?.lowercased().firstCapitalized ?? "Brand Unavailable",
                                        mealName: item.lowercaseDescription?.firstCapitalized ?? "food invalid",
                                        calories: String(Double(round(item.foodNutrients?[3].value! ?? 0.00)).removeZerosFromEnd()),
                                        quantity: 2,
                                        amount: "test",
                                        protein: 2,
                                        carbs: 2,
                                        fat: 2)
                                    )
                                    counter += 1
                                }
                                else{return}
                }
                   
            }
        }
        .resume()
    }
   
}
```

Comment: As an aside, you should probably  use `.search()` for your search bar https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-add-a-search-bar-to-filter-your-data

Comment: I would think the code for `searchFood` would be pretty relevant here. Can you include it?

Comment: is your API working now, can you decode the response, from your previous question?

Comment: your `func searchFood(userItem: String){...} ` is an asynchronous function, that is, 
you need to "wait" until it has finished before using its results. To do this use  a completion handler/closure 
instead of introducing delays in your code.

Comment: Your `userSearchResults` needs to be `@Published` and you need to empty the array before appending a new set of results to it.

Comment: Thank you all for the help and tips. The error though was a relatively minor adjustment

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for the advice and tips. So the actual issue was actually one of relative simplicity. I was just missing emptying the array upon ending the search.

```
if didtextComplete{
      print("complete")
      foodApi.userSearchResults = [] //emptys list
      userFoodInput = ""
}
```

I also marked a var  `didtextComplete = true` when the search was finished. Not the answer I was looking for, but overall it works so I'll remain satisfied for the time being